# simpleCursorAdapter cannot display cursor

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I want to retrieve data from DB. And in my In my DBAdapter, I use `fetchAllBooks` method to get a cursor:

```
 public Cursor fetchAllBooks()
    {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT " + TABLE_TITLE + "." + KEY_TITLE_ID + " As _id, "
                + KEY_TITLE + ", " + KEY_PRICE + ", " + KEY_ISBN
                +", GROUP_CONCAT(" + KEY_AUTHOR + ", ', ') AS authors"
                + " FROM " + TABLE_TITLE + " JOIN " + TABLE_AUTHOR
                + " USING (" + KEY_TITLE_ID + ")"
                + " GROUP BY " + KEY_TITLE_ID;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        return c;
    }
```

In the main activity , I use `fillData` method to fill the ListView:

```
private void fillData() {

    Cursor c = db.fetchAllBooks();
    startManagingCursor(c);
    Log.d("count", c.getCount() + "");// could display the number of book. such as: count: 2; --- means cursor have 2 row(books)
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Log.d("title", BookContract.getTitle(c)); // could display the title of each book;
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    String[] from = new String[] {BookContract.KEY_TITLE, BookContract.KEY_AUTHORS};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.cart_row_title, R.id.cart_row_author};


    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.cart, c, from, to, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

As you see, the LogCat could display the content of cursor. it means that I retrieve the cursor successfully. However, the listView cannot display the book title and the authors. I do not use any `db.close()` or `cursor.close()` in my code.

the `cart_row.xml` which represent each row item in the list view.And the `cart.xml` which contain a list view:

Thanks in advance.

Comment: define `the listView cannot display them`

Comment: @njzk2 you mean replace `setListAdapter(adapter)` with `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); listView.setAdapter(adapter);`? but it still cannot work.

Comment: no. I ask you to define what you mean by that. what happens? (also, where do you call fillData, what is your layout like, what have you tried?)

Comment: @njzk2 I've define it. Is that clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to answer my own question. A little funny...

please pay more attention to this sentence:

> the `cart_row.xml` which represent each row item in the list view. And the `cart.xml` which contain a list view:

The simpleCursorAdapter need `cart_row.xml` instead of `cart.xml`. So change simpleCursorAdapter to:

`adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.cart_row, c, from, to, 0);`

Comment: I was just about to ask for the `cart.xml` file. Glad you figured it out.